# How to check message on uniqueness Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

There is topic `Users` with partitions.

Each partitions have messages about user data.

How to avoid duplications, for example dont allow inserting of the same user's name?

If I got this right I should create seperate topic `Usernames` and append all requested usernames.

Then before adding a new user in topic `Users` I ensure that there are not dublications in topic `Usernames`, right?

Accordingly using streams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are talking about a scenario where you are trying to publish events to Kafka topic from a micro-service. 
Also, assuming you want to publish users profile --> username as key, user profile as value.

There are 2 issues of deduplication here :-

1.) you might get different usernames to your service at different times and publishing to topic.

2.) Duplicate message processing -  During Broker failure(ack not received) or kafka client failures, the same message can be re-processed as kafka client does not hace ack info.

This can be taken care by enabling idempotency on kafka producers and atomic transactions.(Refer to Exactly Once processing)

I believe your question is about 1.) where your service receives duplicate messages.

Solution 1:- 
If you are using micro-service, you can have an inmemory cache/DB of usernames and publish to kafka if duplicate is not found.

Solution 2:- (Handle on Kafka itself using streams)
input topic - users

Build an Kafka Stream client with stateStore(keyValueStore) and transformer to implement your dedupe logic.

So, your kafka stream client consumes the events from users topic and transforms in UserDedupeTransformer(where you have dedupe logic) and then produces to the output topic(as per ur requirement)

```
StoreBuilder<KeyValueStore<String, String>> storeBuilder = Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(
            Stores.persistentKeyValueStore("UserDedupeStoreName"),
            Serdes.String(),
            Serdes.String())
            .withCachingEnabled();

builder.addStateStore(storeBuilder)
            .stream("users-topic", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()))
            .transform(() -> new UsersDedupeTransformer(), "usersDedupeStoreName") 
            .to("destination-topic");
```

In UserDedupeTransformer - Configured userDedupeStore and override the transform method -

```
 public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
        this.context = context;

        dedupeStore = (KeyValueStore<String, String>) context.getStateStore("userDedupeStoreName");
}


 public KeyValue<String, String> transform(String key, String v) {
        if (null != key && null != dedupeStore.get(key))
            return KeyValue.pair(key, value);
        else 
            return null;
```

This dedupe store can be configured as In-Memory and also can be persisted using RocksDB.

Comment: So, then stream result store in topic? And connect consumers to that? How does it works, if stream found duplicate login it does not put data in topic, right and vice versa?

Comment: You can persist to KSQL or KSQLDB if you are planning to use Kafka as ur DB.

you can persist in your own DB with the processor API, but doing sync persists will impact the performance.

I would suggest to use a Kafka Connect Sink to DB or micro-service to insert into DB.